Android Webview error - chromium handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
I want to open a link in Android webview but getting an error
chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
The link works in web chrome.
I have trid adding security config file aslo, but still not working
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config>
     <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">domain url</domain>
     </domain-config>
  </network-security-config>


I have the same issue using flutter_inappwebview.
It appears to have no self signed certificate, it works on IOS no problem at all.
I have tried almost EVERYTHING I can think of to no avail.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I got the solution. It was server issue, they server changed their certificate so we were getting this issue, now they have reverted their changes to old certificate. and so the issue is gone.
